# PHP "Expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"

Tags: php, mysql, oop, fetch

**I have fixed this, there was a problem in the clean function and a few other little errors, thankyou for all your help.**

I seem to have a problem with my PHP Code. I keep getting the errors:

> `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` 
>   `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given`

```
        public function __construct() {
            global $db, $core;

            $this->sessionID = $core->encrypt(session_id());

            $sessionQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE `session_id` = '{$this->sessionId}'");
            $sessionRow = $db->assoc($sessionQuery);

            if($db->num($sessionQuery) > 0) {
                $userQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '{$sessionRow['user_id']}'");
                $this->loggedIn = true;
                $this->userData = $db->assoc($userQ);
            }       
        }       
    }
    $user = new User();

?>  <br /><br />
```

Comment: That is not the code we are looking for

Comment: It is, it has all the queries in it, the functions work fine.

Comment: No, they don't work. Error messages mean, there is something wrong. Where do you call these `mysql_` functions?

Comment: If we don't know, what `$db` is, how can we help him?

Comment: @Josh This is *not* the code we are looking for. Your errors are caused by the `mysql_*` functions which do not appear int he code you've posted. I suspect they are called from within whatever wrapper class `$db` is an instance of. We need to see that class.

Comment: > public function query($string) {
   global $core;
   $string = $core->clean($string);
   return mysql_query($string);
  }
  
  public function assoc($string) {
   global $core;
   $string = $core->clean($string);
   return mysql_fetch_assoc($string);
  }
  
  public function num($string) {
   global $core;
   $string = $core->clean($string);
   return mysql_num_rows($string);
  }

Comment: @Josh Please edit your question to include that code

Comment: @Joshwaa - that's great, but don't post it as comment, edit the question and post it there :)

Comment: What is `$db` and what do the error messages say about the origin (file & line number) of the error? That's definitively not the actual source of the error you've shown.

Comment: what return the $db->query() method? From your example I think it returns true or false and this is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You're passing `$this->sessionId` instead of `$this->sessionID` to the query. Note the difference in capitalization.

Comment: Thankyou! Someone who read the code that I posted and tried to find the error. There's still an error though :/

Comment: If there's still an error, that means that your query either has a syntax error or is not returning anything(like Codemonkey noted in his answer). Are you encrypting `sessionID` before storing it in the database? If you aren't you shouldn't be encrypting it before trying to query it(`$this->sessionID = $core->encrypt(session_id())`). What happens if you run the query manually(command line/shell/query browser)?

Comment: I've changed a few things and I'm getting 
`https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-zjy4uQGU_3k/TW1AU5fqS9I/AAAAAAAADvc/ecAc2LfXOaA/s1600/WOMEN-Y-U-NO-MAKE-SENSE.jpg`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that comment.

Answer (score 3):

`$sessionQuery` is not a valid mysql resource because you are passing the wrong variable in query hence query got failed.

I would suggest to handle mysql error to avoid this type of warnings.

You are storing session id in `$this->sessionID` and using the `$this->sessionId` in query
it should be

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE `session_id` = '{$this->sessionID}'");
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there is a syntax error in your query. Please confirm that your query has no syntax errors by running the query in PhpMyAdmin.

Also you should make sure that PHP is set to report warnings
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

You can check your connection for errors programmatically using `mysql_error`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Check for errors after you've created your connection and after every query you run. The resource object is only `false` if there was a syntax error in your query, and it is easily identifiable by using `mysql_error`

Comment: A query that doesn't return any rows still produces a result set that happens to have no rows in it. FALSE is only returned when the query fails due to an error.

Comment: True, it is mysql_fetch_* functions that return FALSE if there are no rows. Pardon the mixup, I'll correct the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct() {
            global $db, $core;

            $this->sessionID = $core->encrypt(session_id());

            $sessionQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE `session_id` = '{$this->sessionID}'");
            if($sessionQuery){ // newly added line      
            $sessionRow = $db->assoc($sessionQuery);

            if($db->num($sessionQuery) > 0) {
                $userQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '{$sessionRow['user_id']}'");
                $this->loggedIn = true;
                $this->userData = $db->assoc($userQ);
            } 
            } // newly added line      
        }       
    }
    $user = new User();
```

Comment: I've done that and I'm now getting `Notice: Undefined property: User::$sessionId in C:\xampp\htdocs\habcms\inc\user.inc.php on line 13
d97d0031704680f93b135e138e1f514b`

Comment: Now I have edited the QUERY line, there your have saved session at $this->$sessionID but used in query as $sessionId. This is the problem.

Comment: Just look at the  $this->sessionID and
$sessionQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE `session_id` = '{$this->sessionID}'");

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the entire SQL string to `mysql_real_escape_string` in your `clean` function (which for some reason you deleted from your question).

This causes the passed single quotes to be escaped which results in a malformed SQL string which results in FALSE being returned, instead of a valid resource.

```
$sessionQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE `session_id` = '{$this->sessionId}'");
```

---

```
public function query($string) {
    global $core;
    $string = $core->clean($string);
    return mysql_query($string);
}
```

---

```
public function clean($string, $fordb = true) {
    if(is_array($string)) {
        foreach($string as $key => $value) {
            $string[$key] = $this->clean($value, $fordb);
        }

        return $string;
    } else {

        $string = trim($string);
        $input = htmlentities($input, ENT_COMPAT);

        if($fordb == true) {
            $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
            return $string;
        }
    }
}
```